# How do I disable a single option from select

Tags: 7, forms

I have used a taxonomy entity reference to fill the values of a select form field. Based on the user roles, I want to limit the options between *Submitted*, *Reviewed*, *Accepted*, and *Rejected*.

I have used a content type to submit ideas. The field *idea status* is disabled for a *subscriber* role and available for *moderator* role and *approver* role. I want the *Moderator* to get the status Reviewed and Rejected. *Approver* should see Accepted and Rejected status.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: need more info: is this a custom form and if so can you add the code

Comment: @longboardnode This is a content type to submit ideas. The field "idea status" is disabled for a subscriber role and available for moderator role and approver role. I want the moderator to get the status Reviewed and Rejected. Approver should see Accepted and Rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The options can be hidden by a one liner code,

```
unset($form['field_name']['und']['#options'][1]);
```

where

*['field_name']* is the name of the your field

*[1]* is the index of the option in the list

In my case [1] is Submitted, [2] is Reviewed, [3] is Accepted and [4] is Rejected